# What does "Test job not archived" mean?

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, from-chem-se

I am running frequency computation with `geom=connectivity` in Gaussian. It all converges now but at the very end of the last convergence it says:

```
Test job not archived.
```

I have been googling around and I can't find the explanation of what that is supposed to mean.
Can someone share some light in this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably running a combined optimisation and frequency job in Gaussian. (I discourage that, but that's a different issue.)

The line means that the calculation preceding it has been run as a test calculation, see https://gaussian.com/test. An archive entry has not been created. The reasons may be multiple and depend on the actual input file. That's probably the optimisation part. (I'm guessing here, because I do not know your input file.)

Usually archive entries are only produced for single point calculations. For optimisations there is probably a final iteration, which will have an archive entry at the end of the output.

An ordinary frequency calculation should trigger an archive entry at the end of the output of the job.